# Dúvida sobre como compartilhar informações bundle Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

Crie um controle estático para os menus, o objetivo era que cada Bundle registrasse o seu item de menu.

```
<?php

namespace Test\RegisterBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Test\RegisterBundle\Entity\Menu;

class MenuController extends Controller {

    const STANDARD_CONTAINER = '#content-wrapper';

    /**
     *
     * @var ArrayCollection 
     */
    private static $menus;

    public static function register(Menu $m) {
        if (empty(self::$menus)) {
            self::$menus = new ArrayCollection();
        }
        self::$menus->add($m);
    }

    public static function getAll() {
        return self::$menus;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param ArrayCollection $menus
     * @param array $navs
     * @return Menu
     */
    private static function getMenuByNavFromCollection(ArrayCollection $menus, $navs) {
        $e = array_shift($navs);
        foreach (self::$menus as $m) {
            if (!$m instanceof Menu) {
                continue;
            }
            if ($m->getName() != $e) {
                continue;
            }
            if (empty($navs)) {
                return $m;
            } else if ($m->getSubmenu()->count() == 0) {
                return null;
            } else {
                return self::getMenuByNavFromCollection($m->getSubmenu(), $navs);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $location
     * @return Menu
     */
    public static function getMenuByNav($location) {
        $navs = explode('::', $location);
        if (empty($navs) || empty(self::$menus)) {
            return null;
        }
        return self::getMenuByNavFromCollection(self::$menus, $navs);
    }
}



<?php
namespace Test\RegisterBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="menu")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Menu {

    const TYPE_SIDEBAR = 'sidebar';
    const TYPE_LABEL = 'label';

    function __construct() {
        $this->submenu = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=64, nullable=false)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="mode", type="string", length=16, nullable=false)
     */
    private $mode;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="uri", type="string", length=64, nullable=false)
     */
    private $uri;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="remote", type="string", length=64, nullable=false)
     */
    private $remote;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="icon", type="string", length=16, nullable=false)
     */
    private $icon;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="text", nullable=true)
     * @var string 
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="created", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     * @var \DateTime
     */
    private $created;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="modified", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     * @var \DateTime
     */
    private $modified;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Menu", mappedBy="parent")
     * */
    private $submenu;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Menu", inversedBy="submenu")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="parent_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $parent;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Module", inversedBy="menu")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="menu_modules")
     */
    private $module;

    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName() {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function getUri() {
        return $this->uri;
    }

    public function getMode() {
        return empty($this->mode) ? self::TYPE_SIDEBAR : $this->mode;
    }

    public function setMode($mode) {
        $this->mode = $mode;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getIcon() {
        return $this->icon;
    }

    public function getDescription() {
        return $this->description;
    }

    public function getCreated() {
        return $this->created;
    }

    public function getModified() {
        return $this->modified;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return ArrayCollection
     */
    public function getSubmenu() {
        return $this->submenu;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return Menu
     */
    public function getParent() {
        return $this->parent;
    }

    public function getModule() {
        return $this->module;
    }

    public function setId($id) {
        $this->id = $id;
        return $this;
    }

    public function setName($name) {
        $this->name = $name;
        return $this;
    }

    public function setUri($uri) {
        $this->uri = $uri;
        return $this;
    }

    public function setIcon($icon) {
        $this->icon = $icon;
        return $this;
    }

    public function setDescription($description) {
        $this->description = $description;
        return $this;
    }

    public function setCreated(\DateTime $created) {
        $this->created = $created;
        return $this;
    }

    public function setModified(\DateTime $modified) {
        $this->modified = $modified;
        return $this;
    }

    public function setSubmenu($submenu) {
        $this->submenu = $submenu;
        return $this;
    }

    public function setParent($parent) {
        $this->parent = $parent;
        return $this;
    }

    public function setModule($module) {
        $this->module = $module;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getRemote() {
        return $this->remote;
    }

    public function setRemote($remote) {
        $this->remote = $remote;
        return $this;
    }

    public function addMenu(Menu $menu) {
        $this->submenu[] = $menu;
        return $this;
    }

}
```

Minha intenção era no construtor especifico de cada do Bundle, poder registrar seus respectivos menus, contudo, eu preciso resolver a rota e se possível queria acesso ao Doctrine também para registrar esses menus na persistência.

Arqui é uma ilustração do problema e o que eu gostaria de fazer, sei que

> $this->get('router')->generate('register_profile_view')

não existe no contexto abaixo, é apenas um exemplo do que eu precisava.

```
<?php

namespace Test\RegisterBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;
use SBCorp\RegisterBundle\Controller\MenuController;
use SBCorp\RegisterBundle\Entity\Menu;

class RegisterBundle extends Bundle {

    function __construct() {
        $mProfile = new Menu();
        $mProfile->setIcon('fa-th')
                ->setName('My Profile')
                ->setRemote('#content-wrapper')
                ->setUri($this->get('router')->generate('register_profile_view'));


        MenuController::register($mProfile);

    }

}
```

Se tiver outra sugestão de como fazer eu aceito, pois uso a pouco tempo o Symfony e é bem provável de eu estar reinventando a roda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fica melhor se você utilizar [Services](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html) e também o [KnpMenuBundle](https://github.com/knplabs/KnpMenuBundle)
e cada Bundle seu pode fazer contribuições à montagem do contexto do bundle a cada execução.

Veja [Creating Menus as Services](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpMenuBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/menu_service.md)

```
<?php
// src/Acme/MainBundle/Menu/MenuBuilder.php

namespace Acme\MainBundle\Menu;

use Knp\Menu\FactoryInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class MenuBuilder
{
    private $factory;

    /**
     * @param FactoryInterface $factory
     */
    public function __construct(FactoryInterface $factory)
    {
        $this->factory = $factory;
    }

    public function createMainMenu(Request $request)
    {
        $menu = $this->factory->createItem('root');

        $menu->addChild('Home', array('route' => 'homepage'));
        // ... add more children

        return $menu;
    }
}
```

e a configuração do serviço

```
# src/Acme/MainBundle/Resources/config/services.yml
services:

    acme_main.menu.sidebar:
        class: Knp\Menu\MenuItem
        factory_service: acme_hello.menu_builder
        factory_method: createSidebarMenu
        arguments: ["@request"]
        scope: request
        tags:
            - { name: knp_menu.menu, alias: sidebar } # Named "sidebar" this time
```

e obviamente, o acesso a este serviço pode ser feito pelos demais bundles, realizando alteração no contexto.

Comment: Vou estudar essa repostas, contudo, me interessa apenas se ao invocar o menu na primeira ele já tenha os dados de todos os outros Bundles, Se eu tiver 5 Bundles, por exemplo. Se um chamar o menu apenas no primeiro, a entidade que armazena os menus já deveria ter os menus dos outros Bundles, por isso exemplifiquei o uso do construtor, preciso também manter a entidade Menu, mas vou ver esse exemplo, pois não conheço, pode ser que seja realmente a solução.

Comment: É um caminho um pouco mais longo, pois você precisa inserir um padrão de observação, para que seus bundles tenham alterado o objeto menu antes de sua chamada. Estude as camadas do SF2 e você aprenderá muita coisa!